# Hover method in Jquery within asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a web application in which i need to add the possibility of redirection to other views with `JQUERY`.

```
<script>
         $(function () {
              $("rect[fill='#99ccff']").live("hover", function () {
               if (confirm("Voulez-vous gérer le contenu de cet élément ?") == true) {
                location.href = "@Url.Content("~/User/Edit_Content_Project")?id_project=" + "@Model[0]";
                 }

                        });
                        });

  </script>
```

My problem is that the `confirm` box appears two times successively . Besides,  i need that the action of the `hover` event be unactive until i `focus out` the selected element.

How can i change my code to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the one you are looking for,

```
  <script>
         $(function () {
              $("rect[fill='#99ccff']").mouseleave(function(){
               if (confirm("Voulez-vous gérer le contenu de cet élément ?") == true) {
                location.href = "@Url.Content("~/User/Edit_Content_Project")?id_project=" + "@Model[0]";
                 }
              });
         });
    </script>
```